# Modified times of folders

Tags: time, forensics

How does the inheritance and propagation of modified times happen? In order to better put my question, I am going to list three examples:

1. A folder has three files. One file gets modified (by any user or service or application). This changes the modified time of the folder as well. (Common case)
2. A folder has three files of which one file gets modified (again it could be by a service, app or user). But this did not change the modified time of the parent folder.
3. A folder has no file (empty). But let's say when a service ABC runs, it changes its modified time.

So my question is, what is controlling all that? What decides how these modified times will update?

After searching, I found that there is a value in Registry `NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate` but I think this is not for individual files/folders. Please advise.

Comment: You'll want to mention the OS in question. Obviously you're talking windows, but which variants? This is the kind of behavior that might change over the years. Also, have you set up a test case and tried your various scenarios to see what would happen?

Comment: I believe that you’re mixing apples and oranges: `NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate` probably has to do with access times, and the rest of your question has to do with modification times. Beyond that, it depends on how the application works. If it simply opens the file and writes to it, that should not count as a modification to the directory. But, if it creates a temporary file in the same directory, and then deletes it, that *will* count as a modification to the dir. And some editor-type programs may make a copy of a file, and then delete the original and rename the new file to the original name.

Comment: Scott,thank you for your response.I couldn't get *'If it simply opens the file and writes to it, that should not count as a modification to the directory.'*.Let say I have a *job* folder on my desktop and I open a doc in the folder, modify and save it. What I see is that the modification time of job folder changes to the time when the recent file is modified. Doesn't this example fall to the category you mentioned 'should not count as a modification to the directory'?OR do you mean that MS Word deletes the original file and creates new one every time I modify my doc? Thanks again for help!

Comment: @user3020081: Microsoft Word falls into (at least) one of the last two categories I described. If you open a Word document and then look at the folder (with Windows Explorer) with hidden files shown, or list the directory (in Command Prompt) with `dir /a`, you’ll see a hidden temporary file. I don’t know whether Word simply deletes that file when it’s done, or whether it deletes the original file and renames the temporary file, but the result is the same.

Comment: @user3020081: By the way, welcome to Super User. For your information, when you respond to a post or a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott”. That way he gets notified. You can abbreviate, e.g., “@Scot”, or use an entire name (without spaces), e.g., “@ MichaelKohne”. The author of a post is automatically notified of comments to that post. See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [this help page](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @Scott: Thank you for explaining that and for the comment format guideline. I appreciate your time and help.